# MySQL Router how to set windows service name

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysqlrouter

How to set Windows service name with MySQL Router?

As per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysqlrouter.html#option_mysqlrouter_install-service) there is only the option of --install-service, but as it seems, it is a fixed name "MySQLRouter".

```
$ mysqlrouter --config "C:\mysql-router\mysqlrouter.conf" --install-service
```

I've tried passing the service name, as one would do in MySQL Server, but it overwritten the service named "MySQL Router".

How to add multiple MySQL Router services?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing MySQL as a Windows service, you need to first stop the current active server. If it is still running use below command to stop:

```
cd C:
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqladmin" -u root shutdown
```

Install the server as a service using this command:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld" --install
```

Comment: I'm referring to [MySQL Router](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/). Not MySQL Server.

Comment: Sorry I got mistaken!!